# How to sort class objects array using the sort() in C++

Tags: c++, class, sorting, object, lambda

I was doing one programming problem where it is required to sort the class objects.

So, i used `sort()` to sort the array of objects but i couldn't do it, i read somewhere it requires lambda expression to that, but i don't know about them yet.

So, if you can help me with this question with some explanation of lambda expression it would be wonderful.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class CallLog{
    public:
    string pno;
    int dur;
    string da;
    void setpno(string p_no) {pno = p_no;}
    void setdur(int d) {dur = d;}
    void setda(string dsa) {da = dsa;}
    string getpno() {return pno;}
    int getdur() {return dur;}
    string getda() {return da;}
};

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    CallLog arr[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        string pno;
        int dur;
        string da;
        cin >> pno >> dur >> da;
        arr[i].setpno(pno);
        arr[i].setdur(dur);
        arr[i].setda(da);
    }
    sort(arr, arr+n, "what labmda expression to write?" );
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "DialledNumber : " << arr[i].getpno() << ", Duration : " << arr[i].getdur() << ", Date : " << arr[i].getda() << "\n";
    }
}
```

I want to sort these objects with respect to the `int dur`.

Comment: **ProTip:** The variable-length arrays (VLAs) are not supported in C++. Therefore, statements like `cin >> n; CallLog arr[n];` – is invalid. Instead, use a `std::vector` or dynamic memory allocation with `new` and `delete` pair.

Comment: thanks @RohanBari for the Tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting is about comparing elements and knowing which one is "lower" than other one (ie, if I sort `{5,3,1}` into `{1,3,5}`, it is because `1` is lower than `3` and `3` is lower than `5`)

So, it depends on what kind of logic you want to follow for your sorting algorithm (you could, for example, sort them by their member `int dur`). `sort()` uses the `<` operator to sort, so you have two options:

1. Overload the `<` operator as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36056804/11261546) <= I suggest you to do this, for example:

```cpp
bool operator<(CallLog a, CallLog b)
{
    return a.dur < b.dur;
}
```

2. You can actually use a lambda, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26295515/11261546) <= notice that even if it shows how to do it using lambdas, it also shows that writing the `<` operator would be way nicer. [Also here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/), there's an easy-to-read example on how to sort passing a function to `sort()`.

Comment: Note that as mentioned by  Rohan Bari , using `std::vector` is the way

Comment: Thanks for the insights

Comment: thank you sir, it was finally working as desired!

Comment: The overloaded `operator<` should take its parameters by const reference, not by value: `bool operator<(const CallLog &a, const CallLog &b)` You can alternatively implement the `operator` as a member of `CallLog`, eg: `class CallLog { public: ... bool operator<(const CallLog &rhs) const { return dur < rhs.dur; } };`

Answer (score 0):

The predefined STL function objects, located in the FUNCTIONAL header file. There are function objects corresponding to all the major C++ operators. In the table, the letter T indicates any class, either user-written or a basic type. The variables x and y represent
objects of class T passed to the function object as arguments. "bool = greater(T, T) x > y
bool = less(T, T) x < y". Also if you want you can write your own function objects.